# How to debug Eureka Client

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka

I now implement a Spring Microserices Application. In my design, there are 2 services and name as Service A, Service B and including Discovery service and Gateway service so totally there are 4 application services here

I already deploy all services on server

I would like to debug service A at localhost. So I would like to know. Do we have any solution if I start service A on my localhost then it will forward request of service A to my computer and rest of services still use on server.

Do you have any suggestion please let me know